# How to change the position of multiple instances of selected elements

Tags: jquery, dom, dom-manipulation

I need to move the each of the h3 elements from their position below to a new position as first child of .summary-inside-wrapper

Everything I have tried moves an instance of ALL the h3 elements into each summary. I need for only the original within each summary to be moved.

```
<div class="content-main">
   <div class="summary" id="listing_summary_3547">
      <div class="share"></div>
      <div class="summary-inside-wrapper">
         <div class="summary-inside">                <---- TO HERE ---| 
            <div class="left">                                        |
               <div class="title">                                    | 
                  <h3>unique text here 1</h3>      -- MOVE THIS h3 ---|      
                  <p>some other text here</p>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="summary" id="listing_summary_45741">
      <div class="share"></div>
      <div class="summary-inside-wrapper">
         <div class="summary-inside">                <---- TO HERE ---| 
            <div class="left">                                        |
               <div class="title">                                    | 
                  <h3>unique text here 1</h3>   --and MOVE THIS h3 ---|      
                  <p>some other text here</p>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="summary" id="listing_summary_6">
      <div class="share"></div>
      <div class="summary-inside-wrapper">
         <div class="summary-inside">                <---- TO HERE ---| 
            <div class="left">                                        |
               <div class="title">                                    | 
                  <h3>unique text here 1</h3>   --and MOVE THIS h3 ---|      
                  <p>some other text here</p>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have tried insertBefore(), prepend() and many more without the desired results. Each time I get copies of EVERY h3 inside each instance of the summary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code:

```
$(".title h3").each(function()
                    {
                       var item=$(this); 
                       var parentContainer=item.parents(".summary-inside");
                       item.remove();
                       parentContainer.prepend(item);
                    });
```

here is a [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mhCVS/4/)

Comment: This is almost there! It does what I want but the h3 tags are missing. To be more clear- the content from the h3 tags was moved and is in the right position (without copies! yes!!!) but the h3 tags are missing in the new position,

Comment: Nailed it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

this should do the trick

```
 $( ".summary-inside-wrapper" ).each(function() {
    $( this ).prepend( $( this ).find( ".title > h3" ).html() );
    $( this ).find( ".title" ).remove();
});
```

Comment: are you sure this will work and it will not append to the first control found with the class "summary-inside" and not necessarily the parent as he wants?

Comment: Doesn't work. It puts the content of the first h3 into each instance.

Comment: @Baz1nga updated, misunderstood, for some reason I read .summary-inside"

Comment: @RickD try now and change "unique text here 1" to "unique text here 1", "unique text here 2" and "unique text here 3" so you can see the change